# php code that will add spaces in desired positions of the string

Tags: php, string

I have entries like this:

**username08-15-1008-31-1174.86.60.91http://sitename.com/04442**

Where:

- username = username ;)
- 08-15-10 = year
- the rest of the numbers ( 08-31-1174.86.60.91 ) represents another date and ip which do no interest me
- the url of the site
- the first 0 zero after the url is the site's pagerank which can vary from 1 to lets say 7
- the second and third number 44, represents the number of internal links
- the fourth and fifth number represents the number of backlinks

**What I am looking for is a php code that will add "space" after:**

- the username;
- the date;
- the IP (just before http)
- after the url;
- after the first number;
- after the third number

With this spaces I can echo my code, copy paste it into excel and with the help of the spaces I can separate the data into columns. This way, I can manipulate it, lets say the oldest sites, with the greatest number of backlinks and the lowest number of outgoing links. etc.

I am thinking of something like this, but I do not know how to add the spaces:

```
<?
$sites = array(
'username08-15-1008-31-1174.86.60.91http://sitename.com/04442',    
'username08-11-1009-05-1196.44.171.207http://sitename.com/034'
);

foreach ($sites as $site)
{
// HERE WILL BE THE CODE    
echo $site;
}
?>
```

Hope you can help!
Ty!

Comment: In that case, what if the username ends with a number?
myname_ishere_66608-15-1008-31-1174.86.60.91http://sitename.com/04442

Comment: Hoping it won't :(, well most of the aren't. This is a script I will use as raw guidance, don't need it to be super accurate. Very good point btw

Comment: Are you certain there aren't already delimiters. Some unprintable ASCII characters like `NUL` `\0` and `RS` `\036` are common, but wouldn't show up.

Comment: Well I do a copy paste with my mouse from a site which has javascript code rendering it, can I get delimiters somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if I understood correctly, this should do the trick for you:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($sites); ++$i) {
    $sites[$i] = preg_replace("/(\w*)(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\d\d-\d\d-\d\d([\d.]*)(.*\/)(\d)(\d\d)(\d*)/","$1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7",$sites[$i]);
    echo $sites[$i];
}
```

Note that this assumes that your username consists of only letters, numbers or underscores, and that your URL will end with /.

Comment: Ty so much, I have got it to work, but the preg match does not put a space after the url, separating the first number after the url. Then I need to separate the numbers two and three after the url. Ty;)

Comment: From my example, at the end it works perfectly, I get 0 space 44 space 42 ... well the last value, in this case 42 could have three digits

Comment: Do you have any bounds for the values? Obviously the pagerank is always between 1-7. But are the values 2 and 3 and their lengths somehow related to each other? Without any rules it is impossible to make it work completely :(.

Comment: Well I will keep the value nr 2 always having 2 digits

Comment: Edited my post, now I think it should be what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for that:

```
preg_match('/(\w+)(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4})-(\d{2}-\d{2})(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(.*)/',$string,$matches);
```

After this, just use `$matches` as array, to extract each part of string. Concate with whatever spacers you like. `$matches[1].' '.$matches[2].'etc'`

Comment: Wow:) This is why I had to ask, can't see myself writing something like this:) Will test it to see if it works:) Ty!

Comment: This is one minute regex, you could make it more perfect, adding IP, date and URL validators, but for your given question, this should be enough.

Comment: You are pointing with `// HERE WILL BE THE CODE` in right direction :) See updates of my answer...

Comment: Ty, I have got it to work, but the preg match does not put a space after the url, separating the first number after the url. Then I need to separate the numbers two and three after the url. Ty;)